# Converting a Dynamic Range into a string type

Tags: excel, type-conversion, vba

I have a column of string types (email addresses) that potentially can change in length, in that people can add or remove email addresses in this column. (The range of the column is dynamic) Currently, I have code that takes a fixed range and converts the range into a long string delimited by semicolons. Is there a way that I can grab all the cells with values in this column and convert the range into a string type?

My current code

```
EmailAddresses = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("P2:P12").Value), "; ")
```

If I change the range to "P:P" I receive a runtime error that I'm out of memory...given that it's making a string out of blank cells

Comment: have you looked at Workbook.UsedRange

Comment: I looked into that but I thought that selected all cells with values in the workbook. Wasn't sure how to apply that to just 1 column

Comment: Workbook.UsedRange.Rows.Count = now you have the total number of rows and you can just set the column.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to VBA, and this is probably a dumb question, but what do you mean to set the column? If I know that then I can proceed with the rest

Comment: Something like EmailAddresses = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("P2:P" & Cstr(ActiveWorkbook.UsedRange.Rows.Count) ).Value), "; ")

Comment: I got a runtime error '438'
Object does not support this property or method, with that line of code highlighted

Comment: My bad, UsedRange is a worksheet property not a workbook Try: EmailAddresses = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("P2:P" & Cstr(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) ).Value), "; ")

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the job, everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the addresses are not the result of formulas, try a simple loop:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim EmailAddresses As String
    EmailAddresses = ""
    For Each r In Range("P:P").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            EmailAddresses = EmailAddresses & ";" & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
    EmailAddresses = Mid(EmailAddresses, 2)
End Sub
```

You might even do away with the test against **""** if there are no *Nulls* in the column.